# SQL Full Text Search - Same score given to words in different order

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a simple SQL database that looks like this..

```
name
-------------
walker avenue
avenue walker
```

I have created a full text index and am doing a search like this..

```
SELECT
    value,
    MATCH (value) AGAINST ('walker avenue') AS score,
FROM
    `example`
WHERE
    MATCH (value) AGAINST ('walker avenue')
ORDER
    BY (score) DESC
```

But the results are giving the same score to `walker avenue` and `avenue walker` like this...

```
value         | score
------------------------------------
avenue walker | 0.062016263604164124
walker avenue | 0.062016263604164124
```

I assume this is because both results contain both of the search terms exactly, but it doesn't matter that they are in a different order.

How can I get it to give a higher score to `walker avenue` because this contains the words in the correct order?